# Find an example such that $X_n\to 0$ in probability but $X_{N(n)}\to 1$ a.s. with $N(n)\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

It is an exercise from Durrett's probability.

Find an example with $X_n\in \{0,1\}$,$X_n\to 0$ in probability, $N(n)$ increases to infinity a.s. and $X_{N(n)}\to 1$ a.s.

I was thinking that first we divide $[0,1]$ into two equal pieces and let $X_1=1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ and $X_2=1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$. Then we divide $[0,1]$ into four equal pieces and define $X_3=1_{[0,\frac{1}{4}]}$ and $X_4=1_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]}$ and so on. So we have $$X_{2^n+m}=1_{[\frac{m}{2^n},\frac{m+1}{2^n}]} \text{ for } 1\leq m < n$$

$X_n\to 0$ in probability, but I could not find a subsequence $N(n)$ which satisfies the above condition.

Comment: Think $X_i$ independent with $P(X_i=1)\to 0$ and $\sum_{i\ge 1} P(X_i=1)=\infty$. Then apply Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a convergent sequence it implies that all sub-sequences must converge at the same value, because having a sequence with sub-sequences approaching two values would imply that it isn't caunchy (i.e. the points don't get infinitesimally closer as $n\to \infty$) which means it isn't convergent. So either $X_n\to 1$ or $X_{N(n)}\to 0$ not both.

Comment: No. One convergence is almost sure while the other is in probability, so the contradiction is not there.

Comment: @Did How is contradiction not there? If $X_{N_n}\to 1$ a.s., then $X_{N_n}\to 1$ in probability, so we can't have $X_n\to 0$ in probability.

Comment: @A.S. Funny, the example you gave in the comment on main contradicts what you just wrote: consider $(X_n)$ independent Bernoulli with $P(X_n=1)=x_n$, $P(X_n=0)=1-x_n$, $x_n\to0$, $\sum\limits_nx_n$ diverges, and $(N_n)$ the (random) sequence of times such that $X_{N_n}=1$ for every $n$ (which exists since $X_n=1$ infinitely often, almost surely). Then $X_n\to0$ in probability (because $x_n\to0$) and $X_{N_n}\to1$ almost surely.

Comment: True, but the subtlety is that $N(n)$ depends on particular realization of $X_i$'s i.e. random.